# Use .htaccess to redirect something.php to /something-keywords-for-seo/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a very basic website that uses an `.htaccess` file. The website itself is just static PHP pages, such like `www.domain.com/about.php.`

I'm struggling to work out how I can use .htaccess to change the URL to `www.domain.com/about-something-seo-friendly/.`

Currently I've attempted;

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /(.*)\.php($|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

This simply uses the part before the `.php` for the name, which isn't entirely what I want, but for testing purposes. Although this works, the page then renders with 0 graphics, just plain text.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you already changed the URL in your application? The problem here is the `-something-seo-friendly` part... if you are _changing_ the URL structure then how do we map `about.php` to `about-something-seo-friendly`? If preserving existing SEO is not a concern then that isn't an issue.

Comment: Quite honestly this is all new to me, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)